# How to detect if text in the text view is nil in all lines in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uitextview, whitespace

I have a text view in my project that can detect if the user just pushes the space button. But the problem is that when the user taps the enter button to go to another line, the app can't detect that it's still nil.

Here is the code for checking if the user just tapped space and wants to send that text:

```
if chatTexts!.text.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespaces).isEmpty
{
    // string contains non-whitespace characters
    print("SPACE")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines` for this purpose, which can detect empty lines as well.

```
if chatTexts!.text.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty {
    [...]
}
```